Run some commands as root in Android application
I have spent around 2days looking for an answer, but at a complete loss now.
I'm writing an Android application in Kotlin that has to access a file node in /proc/xxxx/xxxxxx.
(a). I have to setenforce 0 and chmod 666 /proc/xxxx/xxxxxx to access the file.
The target devices use eng or userdebug build image, so adb root and su are available.
Which means I can adb root and execute (a) in adb shell then run my application, and it does work fine.
The problem is when I trying to achieve (a) in my application by
val p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(arrayOf("su", "root", "setenforce", "0"))

BTW, su root setenforce 0 works in non-root adb shell.
I always get
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "su": error=13, Permission denied

My question is

What exactly causes the "Permission denied"?
How can I run su in application?
If 2 is no possible, is there any trick to run commands that need root permission in application?
Can I setenforce or access file in /proc/ without root?

Thank you in advance!
At first, I thought it's the file permission of su, which was rwsr-x---, owner: root, group: shell. Then I chmod 777 su but still get the same exception.

Possibly related: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/232763/3573
